# Modify and print state using STM

Tags: haskell, stm

I'm able to initialise a state using STM and print it out:

```
module Main where

import Control.Concurrent.STM

data State = State {name :: String} deriving (Show)

type MyAppState = TVar [State]

initState :: STM MyAppState
initState = newTVar [State "hi"]

main :: IO ()
main =  
  do 
    state <- atomically initState
    stateToPrint <- readTVarIO state
    putStrLn (show stateToPrint)
```

I have tried to create function to update the state:

```
updateState :: String -> State -> State 
updateState newName s = State newName : s
```

But I'm not sure how to place it in the main 'do' block without the compiler throwing an error since it expects a type of `State` but it is passed a `MyAppState`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**`writeTVar :: TVar a -> a -> STM ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Conc.html#v:writeTVar):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
    state <- atomically initState
    stateToPrint <- readTVarIO state
    putStrLn (show stateToPrint)
    atomically (readTVar state >>= writeTVar state . fmap (updateState "foo"))
```

We here thus read the content of the `state`, then we pass it through an `fmap updateState` to update the elements in the list, and then we write that to the `state` var.

That being said, it might be useful to look for a state monad transformer, like in the [**`Control.Monad.Trans.State`** module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State.html) of the [**`transformers`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/).

Note that your `updateState` function is not properly defined, you perhaps want to define this like:

```
updateState :: String -> State -> State 
updateState newName (State s) = State (newName ++ s)
```

Comment: Sorry just one more thing, I think that there may be a problem with how I defined my state. I'm getting the error: "Couldn't match expected type ‘[State]’ with actual type ‘State’"

Comment: @timothyylim: did you use `fmap`? By defining your `TVar` to store a *list* of `State`s, you need some way to handle such list.

Comment: Yep, am using fmap as suggested!

Comment: @timothyylim: the error is in your `updateStateFunction`.